# Codeigniter not sending through JangoSMTP

Tags: codeigniter, smtp

I am trying to send an email using codeigniter through JangoSMTP and for whatever reason the script takes about 60-70 seconds then gives me an error on the last portion of the process, the send.

Here is CI's debug..

```
*220 relay.jangosmtp.net ESMTP Welcome to the JangoSMTP trackable email relay system.; Thu, 05 May 2011 19:08:15 -0000

hello: 250-relay.jangosmtp.net Hello netdesk.aiwebsystems.com [173.236.184.252], pleased to meet you.

250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES

250-SIZE

250-EXPN

250-ETRN

250-ATRN

250-DSN

250-CHECKPOINT

250-8BITMIME

250-AUTH CRAM-MD5 PLAIN LOGIN DIGEST-MD5

250-STARTTLS

250 HELP

from: 250 2.1.0 ... Sender ok

to: 250 2.1.5 ... Recipient ok; will forward

to: 250 2.1.5 ... Recipient ok; will forward

data: 354 Enter mail, end with "." on a line by itself

The following SMTP error was encountered: 

Unable to send email using PHP SMTP. Your server might not be configured to send mail using this method.

User-Agent: CodeIgniter

Date: Thu, 5 May 2011 14:08:16 -0500

From: "Ryan Thompson" 

Return-Path: 

To: service@aiwebsystems.com

Subject: =?utf-8?Q?Email_Test_SMTP?=

Reply-To: "service@aiwebsystems.com" 

X-Sender: service@aiwebsystems.com

X-Mailer: CodeIgniter

X-Priority: 3 (Normal)

Message-ID: <4dc2f5a0b3518@aiwebsystems.com>

Mime-Version: 1.0

Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8

Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit

Testing the email class.*
```

Here is the simple code I am using to send in a sandbox controller..

```
   function smtp(){
        $this->load->library('email');

        $config['protocol'] = 'smtp';
        $config['smtp_host'] = 'relay.jangosmtp.net';
        $config['smtp_user'] = 'MYUSERNAME';
        $config['smtp_pass'] = 'MYPASS';

        $this->email->initialize($config);

        $this->email->from('myemail@aiwebsystems.com', 'Ryan Thompson');
        $this->email->to('myemail@aiwebsystems.com'); 

        $this->email->subject('Email Test SMTP');
        $this->email->message('Testing the email class.');  

        $this->email->send();

        echo $this->email->print_debugger();
    }
```

I tested this exact same thing with my regular email host and creds and it popped one off perfectly.

I don't have any IP restrictions or From: restrictions at Jango. I am authing only as username/pass.

My CI Version is 2.0.0

I am at the end of my wits!! My Email.php class file is un-edited.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [here](http://blog.jangomail.com/2011/06/smtp-relay-and-codeigniter.html)

The problem is likely due to the fact that CodeIgniter defaults to using LF as the line terminator, rather than CRLF required by RFC.  Add this code:

```
$this->config['crlf'] = '\r\n';
$this->config['newline'] = '\r\n';
```

Comment: hi @DeanGoodman, I added these 2 lines to my config, but i'm still getting an error when I send to my gmail `error:Email address is not verified.`. It only works when I send to the same domain from which I sent the message. Any thoughts on this? thanks